# need to match 2 columns of 2 different pandas dataframe if it matches we need to attach new data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

hi I have 2 csv file which are very huge

df1

```
x   y  z      keywords
a   b  c  [apple,iphone,watch,newdevice]
e   w  q   NaN
w   r  t  [pixel,google]
s   t  q  [india,computer]
d   j  o  [google,apple]
```

df2

```
name       stockcode   
apple.inc      appl   
lg.inc          weew   
htc.inc         rrr    
google.com     ggle
```

now i need to check m values in df1 with new value in df2 if it matches i need to combine the details of new values to df1 else we need to fill with null values

I need to use python  please help me

sample output

```
x   y  z      keywords                        stockcode    
a   b  c  [apple,iphone,watch,newdevice]       aapl    
e   w  q   NaN                                 null    
w   r  t  [pixel,google,]                      ggle    
s   t  q  [india,computer]                     null    
d   j  o  [google,apple]                      aapl,ggle
```

I have written this code but it is only comparing one keyword and giving one stock code i need out 2 stockcodes if we have 2 keywords which are matching in df2

```
df1['stockcode'] = np.nan
#mapping data 
for indexKW,valueKW in df1.keyword.iteritems():
    for innerVal in valueKW.split():
        for indexName, valueName in df2['Name'].iteritems():
            for outerVal in valueName.split():
                if outerVal.lower() == innerVal.lower():
                    df1['stockcode'].loc[indexKW] = df2.Identifier.loc[indexName]
```

output for above program

```
x   y  z      keywords                        stockcode    
a   b  c  [apple,iphone,watch,newdevice]       aapl    
e   w  q   NaN                                 null    
w   r  t  [pixel,google,]                      ggle    
s   t  q  [india,computer]                     null    
d   j  o  [google,apple]                       ggle
```

for last row I have 2 keywords that are matching in df2 but I am getting only one matching stockcode of keyword google I need to get stockcode for apple also , as shown in sample ouput.

sample output:-

```
x   y  z      keywords                        stockcode    
a   b  c  [apple,iphone,watch,newdevice]       aapl    
e   w  q   NaN                                 null    
w   r  t  [pixel,google,]                      ggle    
s   t  q  [india,computer]                     null    
d   j  o  [google,apple]                      aapl,ggle
```

Please help me guys

Comment: Please check my solution and [`upvote and accept`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if any of the solutions provided your required result.

Answer (score 2):

You Can transform df2 to a lookup dictionary and then map it to df1 ;)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


data1 = {'x':'a,e,w'.split(','),
         'keywords':['apple,iphone,watch,newdevice'.split(','),
                    np.nan,
                    'pixel,google'.split(',')]}
data2 = {'name':'apple lg htc google'.split(),
        'stockcode':'appl weew rrr ggle'.split()}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

mapper = df2.set_index('name').to_dict()['stockcode']

df1['stockcode'] = df1['keywords'].replace(np.nan,'').apply(lambda x : [mapper[i] for i in x if (i and i in mapper.keys())])
df1['stockcode'] = df1['stockcode'].apply(lambda x: x[0] if x else np.nan)
```

Comment: Had no idea you could create a dict from two series like that, +1 very cool

Comment: @Datanovice Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply` and `map` with `join` as:

```
df2.set_index('name',inplace=True)
df1.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x['keywords']).map(df2['stockcode']).dropna().values,1)

0          [appl]
1              []
2          [ggle]
3              []
4    [ggle, appl]
dtype: object
```

Or:

```
df1.apply(lambda x: ','.join(pd.Series(x['keywords']).map(df2['stockcode']).dropna()),1)

0         appl
1             
2         ggle
3             
4    ggle,appl
dtype: object
```

Or:

```
df1.apply(lambda x: ','.join(pd.Series(x['keywords']).map(df2['stockcode']).dropna()),1)\
                       .replace('','null')
0         appl
1         null
2         ggle
3         null
4    ggle,appl
dtype: object
```

---

```
df1['stockcode'] = df1.apply(lambda x: ','.join(pd.Series(x['keywords'])\
                                          .map(df2['stockcode']).dropna()),1)\
                             .replace('','null')
print(df1)
   x  y  z                           keywords  stockcode
0  a  b  c  [apple, iphone, watch, newdevice]       appl
1  e  w  q                                NaN       null
2  w  r  t                    [pixel, google]       ggle
3  s  t  q                  [india, computer]       null
4  d  j  o                    [google, apple]  ggle,appl
```